# Rails render within before_action incorrect format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to render template within `before_action` and it's being rendered with html format. Request is in :js format.

```
def check_destroy
  p request.format
  render partial: 'layouts/alert', locals: {type: 'info', message: 'my message from check destroy', title: 'my title'}
end
```

Log output:

```
:js
Rendered layouts/_alert.html.slim (5.3ms)
```

If I set `respond_to :js` before render everything works well.

```
Rendered layouts/_alert.js.erb (0.7ms)
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: It is behaving as expected, you need to specify it to render the output in js format

Comment: but if I put same render into action itself, js format is being rendered. Why? I don't see any info about this in docs

Comment: Because you need to wrap it in a `respond_to` block or the default format will be rendered. Its not really that mysterious.

Comment: but request format is set to js, why it should be default?

Comment: I want template format based on request format http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-formats-option

Answer (score 0):

I won't bet you can render a partial from a controller, think about sharing what you want to display between your two responses types.

You'd need :

- `_alert.html.slim` (contains the content you want to display)
- `alert.html.slim` (only contains a call to your partial, is used for html responses)
- `alert.js.rb` (contains a call to your partial that you can manipulate via jq/js, is used on js responses)

In js.erb :

```
$("your_selector").html("<%= j(render partial: "/layouts/alert", locals: {…}) %>");
```

<sub><sup>(Wrap your render with `j(…)`, short for `escape_javascript`, needed</sup></sub>

In html.slim :

```
<%= render partial: "/layouts/alert", locals: {…} %>
```

You'll set your controller as below :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render template: 'layouts/alert' } # will pick alert.html.slim template
  format.js { render template: 'layouts/alert' } # will pick alert.js.erb template
end
```

Template based should work too with this setup, using the following :

```
render formats: [:html, :js]
```

This pattern got quite obsolete, but this how you can do it with rails via a controller

Comment: I need render html and js both. And I have both templates with same name: joxi.net/ZrJ8Meu9KwjD2j

Comment: I've edited my answer. I believe that you don't want to render partial from a controller, so if you want to respond to both html and js reponse, you need alert.(js.erb + html.slim) templates, and you share your partial between both